# UISwipeGestureRecognizer diagonal swipe issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Well, I have some code to add 4 recognizers to a view, like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    for(int d = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; d <= UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown; d = d*2) {
         UISwipeGestureRecognizer *sgr = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
         sgr.direction = d;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:sgr];
    }
    [self restore];
    [self populate];
    [self displaymap];
```

}

and a recognizer like this

```
-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
printf("Guesture: %d\n", recognizer.direction);
if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
{
    printf("a\n");
    [self move: 'a'];
}
else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
{
    printf("d\n");
    [self move: 'd'];
}
else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
{
    printf("w\n");
    [self move: 'w'];
}
else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)
{
    printf("s\n");
    [self move: 's'];
}
else if (recognizer.direction == (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp))
{
    printf("y\n");
    [self move: 'd'];
}
}
```

The problem is, it never detects the up | right direction, anybody know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s not how the `direction` property works. UISwipeGestureRecognizer only recognizes swipes in a single direction at a time. You’ll need to do something more complicated involving a UIPanGestureRecognizer and determining its direction from the result of its `-translationInView:` / `-velocityInView:` methods.

Comment: I am a little bad with programatically adding recognizers, do you think you could get me started?

Comment: Okay, I got one functional, am I supposed to be dividing the translationInView and velocityInView or is the / used as a "use this or that"?

Comment: “use this or that”. `-velocityInView:` is probably the better option—as soon as its magnitude goes above a certain threshold you can trigger the gesture in the direction described by that vector.

Comment: Thank you, works perfect. I actually checked the state and used velocity